# Update dateTime column with laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a pins table in my database with a pin_date column.

In my migration I have this:

`$table->dateTime('pin_date')->nullable();`

I have a button that points to a post route

```
Route::post('/pins/pin-date/{id}', 'PinsController@pinDate');
```

that leads to a pinDate controller method:

```
public function pinDate($id)
{
    $pin = Pin::find($id);

    $pin->save();
}
```

I want to update the pin-date column in the database to the current date and time when I click the button and hit the route. I am not really sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do this whenever the model is `saving`, you can bind to the `boot` function of the `model` and set it there:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($pin) {
        $pin->pin_date = \Carbon::now()
    });
}
```

If you want to update this value instead of handling it whenever the model is saved - such as through a button click, you can use Ajax. You will need 1.) a route, 2.) a click handler, 3.) an AJAX request and 4.) a controller to handle processing the request:

Click handler with Ajax:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/route/to/update/my/pin' + $(this).closest('.pin').data('id')
    });
});
```

Then a route:

```
Route::post('/route/to/update/my/pin/{id}', 'PinController@updatePinDate');
```

Then make the controller method and update it accordingly:

```
public function updatePinDate(Request $request, Pin $pin)
{
    $pin->pin_date = \Carbon::now();
    $pin->save();
}
```

If you don't want to use javascript, you can just use a standard form with the same route/controller methods:

```
<form action="/route/to/update/my/pin/{{ $pin->id }}" method="POST">
     {{csrf_field()}}

     <button type="Submit"> Update Pin Date </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok and how would I make it so when the button gets clicked it triggers that?

Comment: @L.Fox AJAX. Use Javascript to make a POST request to a route, route that method to a controller. Sorry, I must've missed that. Are you using any javascript frameworrk, or jQuery?

Comment: I actually am fairly new to laravel and have almost no experience with JavaScript so I am not using any JavaScript

Comment: @L.Fox Added all the methods and info you should need to accomplish this, with and without javascript

Comment: Get rid of the `\Carbon::now();` and use just `now()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function pinDate($id)
{
    $pin = Pin::find($id);
    $pin->pin_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $pin->save();
}
```

I hope it works.